# "Unresolvable dependency resolving" error custom validation in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

To make a custom validation rule in laravel **5.1** , I created a class named `CustomValidators` in `App/Validatiors` directory like this :

```
namespace  App\Validators;

    use App\Classes\Utilities;

    class CustomValidators extends \Illuminate\Validation\Validator
    {
        public function DateTime ($field , $value ,$param, $validator){
            dd($value);
        }
    }
```

And in `AppServiceProvider.php` , I added this :

```
Validator::extend('date_time', 'App\Validators\CustomValidators@DateTime');
```

and in `store()` function of a Controller I used it like this :

```
$rules = array (
                'start_publish' => 'date_time',
            );
```

But when running App , this error occured :

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 824:
Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #1 [ <required> array $data ]] in class Illuminate\Validation\Validator
```

Of curse when I define **DateTime()** function directly in `AppServiceProvider.php` all things works like this :

```
Validator::extend('date_time', function ($field , $value ,$param, $validator){
                dd($value);
            });
```

What is Problem while I follow [custom validation laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem

I should not to extend `\Illuminate\Validation\Validator` when defining `CustomValidators` class beacause it automatically extends `Validator` class via :

```
Validator::extend('date_time', 'App\Validators\CustomValidators@DateTime');
```

in fact `CustomValidators` class must be like this :

```
namespace  App\Validators;

    use App\Classes\Utilities;

    class CustomValidators
    {
        public function DateTime ($field , $value ,$param, $validator){
            dd($value);
        }
    }
```